# JSON with full hierarchy in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an hierarchical structure in my app:

- Environment has Containers
- Container has Items
- Item has expression

so my Model code looks like:

```
class Environment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :containers, :dependent => :destroy

  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: :containers))
  end

end

class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :environment

  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: :items))
  end

end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :expressions, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :container

  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: :expressions))
  end

end

class Expression < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item

def as_json(options = {})
  super()
end

end
```

In a *regular get of a record* I usually need only one hierarchy below the desired record, that's why in the `as_json` I merge only one hierarchy down (get Environment will return a collection of containers but those containers will not have Items)

**My Question:**

Now what I need is to add a *method* to the controller that allows full hierarchy response i.e. `GET /environment/getFullHierarchy/3` will return: **environment with id=3 with all its containers and for every container all it's Items & for every Item all it's expressions.** without breaking the current as_json

I'm kinda new to Rails, wirking with Rails 4.2.6 & don't know where to start -  can anyone help?

Comment: try https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: thanks @sethi, can you please explain how can I use this gem? the docs arn't clear enugh, can you show this on my example?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it goes something like this hopefully you get the idea.

EnvironmentSerializer.new(environment) to get the hierarchy json.

lets say environments table has columns  environment_attr1 , environment_attr2

```
class EnvironmentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :environment_attr1, :environment_attr2 , :containers

  # This method is called if you have defined a 
  # attribute above which is not a direct value like for
  # a rectancle serializer will have attributes length and width
  # but you can add a attribute area as a symbol and define a method
  # area which returns object.length * object.width
  def containers
     ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(object.containers,
           each_serializer: ContainerSerializer)
  end
end

class ContainerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :container_attr1, :container_attr2 , :items
   def items
     ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(object.items,
        each_serializer: ItemSerializer)
   end
end



   class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   ... 
   end

   class ExpressionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   ... 
   end
```

Comment: This obviously can be better written just a example

Comment: You could also probably replace the `containers` and `items` methods with `has_many :containers, serializer: ContainerSerializer` and `has_many :items, serializer: ItemSerializer`. I believe this would have the same effect and be a little more ActiveModelSerializer-ish.

Comment: this is look very promising but how can I keep also my original behavior - when calling :index - retrive only one level down the heirarchy, how does the controller look with those 2 serializers?

Comment: The original behaviour is untouched remember EnvironmentSerializer.new(environment).to_json will give you the hierarchy.